# access DB string to date conversion issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

i have a boatload of access queries that work using manual input. I.E. when the query is run a dialogue pops up something like START-DATE and then another with END-DATE.

the DB criteria is:

```
between [START-DATE] AND [END-DATE]
```

the start and end dates are always the 1st day of the previous month and the last day of the previous month.

I want to replace the criteria with a calculated version, so that no input is required, but the column definition is 6 characters, of the form YYMMDD.

I'm stuck, overthinking this, with questions like

"what about if the current month is january?"
or "how do I handle months with 30/31/29 days ?"

Is there a simple solution to this using Access criteria?

Any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The logic I'm going to use, is the following:

1. Get the current date with `Date()`.
2. Use `DateSerial` to make that the first day of the current month.
3. For the last day of the last month: substract 1 day. For the first day of the last month, substract 1 month.

The first day of the current month: `DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)`

The first day of the last month: `DateAdd('m', -1, DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1))`

The last day of the last month: `DateAdd('d', -1, DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1))`

Now, you could go formatting this as a string, and comparing strings, but the better way is to cast that column to a date (except if you have an index on it, then formatting these dates as strings is way faster):

```
DateSerial(Left(MyColumn, 2), Mid(MyColumn, 3, 2), Right(MyColumn, 2))
Between 
    DateAdd('m', -1, DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)) 
    And DateAdd('d', -1, DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1))
```

This should handle anything you throw at it: leap years, january, short months, etc.

Comment: And this works nicely too. Access doesn't support the cast method, (as far as I could tell), so I formatted the date into strings. I like this solution even more than the one I cobbled together :) So, I'll update my comments below and the the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `Like` in criteria:

```
Like Format(Date(), "YYMM") & "*"
```

For previous month, replace `Date()` by `Date()-Day(Date())`

Answer (score 0):

DateSerial and a little math will do it:

```
FirstDayPreviousMonth: DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1)
LastDayPreviousMonth: DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
```

Thus, if your date field is DateTime:

```
Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
```

If you by

> 6 characters, of the form YYMMDD

mean that the field holds Text, you should change that. Always handle dates as true date values. If it just is the format of the field, it doesn't matter.

For a text field, either just format the date values:

```
Between Format(DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1), "\'yymmdd\'") And Format(DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0), "\'yymmdd\'")
```

or use Patrick's method:

```
Like Format(DateAdd('m', -1, Date()), "\'yymm*\'")
```

Comment: Easier said than done. I don’t own the DB. I have to work with the data that is, not the data I want. This why I added the information about the data being a string.

Comment: for some reason your solution fails to return the first day of the previous month. Patrick's solution didn't work at all as a criteria but was fine when created a macro using the same format.  I wound up combining your's and Patrick's solution, so that the query now works in January as well. I put the solution into my answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was a combination of two of the three responses, because each of them alone did not return the desired result:

```
Like Left(Format(DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,1),"yymmdd"),2) & Format(DateAdd('m',-1,Date()),"mm") & "*"
```

This works for all months, and returns all days in the previous month

Eric's solution is nice too and when I revised it to include **format** it also gave me the desired result, and also works for all months.

```
Between Format(DateAdd('m',-1,DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)),"yymmdd") And Format(DateAdd('d',-1,DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)),"yymmdd")
```

Comment: Note that if you implemented my full solution (including the code casting your column to a date), you wouldn't need to modify it, and the resulting code would likely be more efficient.